# Are CTAF and UNICOM frequencies routinely recorded?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, radio-communications

ATC communications are recorded for later examination by accident investigators or regulatory agencies. Are CTAF frequencies at untowered fields usually recorded? How about manned UNICOM frequencies?

Comment: They don't really have to: they have liveatc.net ;)

Comment: At my part-time-towered airport, we used to keep all frequencies keyed up overnight—including the Tower frequency, which becomes the CTAF after we close. Within the past year we were informed that, due to some legal agreement somewhere, we aren't supposed to record the frequencies when we aren't open and our new SOP is to deselect all frequencies (at least RX capability) as part of the closing checklist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the AIM:

> 4−1−4. Recording and Monitoring
>
> > a. Calls to air traffic control (ATC) facilities (ARTCCs, Towers, FSSs, Central Flow, and Operations Centers) over radio and ATC operational telephone lines (lines used for operational purposes such as controller instructions, briefings, opening and closing flight plans, issuance of IFR clearances and amendments, counter hijacking activities, etc.) **may be monitored and recorded** for operational uses such as accident investigations, accident prevention, search and rescue purposes, specialist training and evaluation, and technical evaluation and repair of control and communications systems.
> >
> > b. Where the public access telephone is recorded, a beeper tone is not required. In place of the “beep” tone the FCC has substituted a mandatory requirement that persons to be recorded be given notice they are to be recorded and give consent. Notice is given by this entry, consent to record is assumed by the individual placing a call to the operational facility.

The use of "may be" for the manned stations would hint at a "no" for the CTAF, UNICOM, etc. (Applies to *official* recording, liveatc not included.)

Comment: Let's just say: If the audio of UNICOM/CTAF is available for listening on www.liveatc.net, it is recorded anyway. If not: Then it will probably won't/might be recorded